# Newman library - return response data value for each iteration into csv

Tags: postman, newman

I am running a data-driven postman collection using the newman libary. I am trying to write the value for 'cost' for each dataset to CSV, in the 4th column (sample CSV below).

I have extracted the 'cost' value using event 'request' and created a function to write the value to the csv.

```
}).on('request', (error, data) => {
    if (error) {
        throw error;
    } 
    var costReturned = JSON.parse(data.response.stream.toString()).cost;
    returnCost(costReturned );
});

function returnCost(costReturned){
    fs.readFile('./testcsv.csv','utf8', (error, data) => {
        if (error) {
            throw error;
        }
        const jsonData = papa.parse(data, { header: true });
        jsonData.data.map((item, index) => item.cost = costReturned[index]);
        const returnedCostsCSV = papa.unparse(jsonData.data);       
        fs.writeFile('./returnedCosts.csv', returnedCostsCSV, (error) => {
            if (error) {
                throw error;
            }
        });
```

However, I get this error. I am unsure if I need to create a loop to iterate through each dataset & write the cost in each row for each request or if there is another way.

```
jsonData.data.map((item, index) => item.cost= costReturned[index]);
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

CSV,
ID,name,address,cost
1,test1, 233 homes street,-
2, test2, 244 highem road,-
3, test3, 1 high str,-

Example Response body:
{
    "cost": 48.00,
    "min": 4.000,
    "max": 266.95
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: is cost an array ?

Comment: @PDHide - no, cost is captured at runtime for each dataset imported from the csv.

Comment: costReturned[index] why is index being called if its not an array . also print costReturned before passing it to the function see if its actually retreiving it

Comment: Thank you - the issue was i was not passing the costreturned into an array. 

Answer (score 0):

There is a chance costReturned is lexically out-of-bounds. It is not possible to discern without additional information. Thus - providing an accurate, helpful answer is also impossible.

I recommend uploading your collection.

I also recommend decoupling "returnCost", or renaming it. Seeing as, returning the cost is **definitely** not what that function is doing. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: the function should be called something like 'returnCostToCSV'